# Versioning multiple projects with versioneer within a single git repository

Tags: python, git, version-control, git-tag, python-versioneer

I have a single, large git repo with many different projects (not submodules). A few of these projects are Python projects for which I'd like to track versioning with Python's `versioneer`, others may be completely independent projects (say, in Haskell). i.e. The directory structure looks like this:

```
myrepository
├── .git
├── README.md
├── project1/
│   ├── project1/
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── _version.py
│   ├── versioneer.py
│   ├── setup.cfg
│   └── setup.py
├── project2/
├── project3/
└── project4/
    ├── project4/
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── _version.py
    ├── versioneer.py
    ├── setup.cfg
    └── setup.py
```

This doesn't play well with `versioneer` because it can't discover the `.git` directory at the project root level, so I get a version of `0+unknown`.

Questions:

1. Is there a suggested way to use versioneer with a single monolithic repo with multiple projects?
2. Depending on the answer to the above, is it recommended that my git tags read like: `project1-2.1.0`, `project2-1.3.1`, or should I unify the git tags like: `1.2.1`, `1.2.2`?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to separate the projects into different directories with related modules in the same directory?

Comment: ^Sorry, I'm not sure if I follow your question, the projects are separated in directories as you can see. The only modules that they share are third-party modules (e.g. `nose`, `scipy`). In practice, each project directory could have been a separate repo, but it's unified under a monolithic repo for a few organizational/collaborative reasons.